# Cocoa prevent window activation

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible to prevent a window in Cocoa to become activated/focused?
I'm working on Qt but need to implement their custom macEvent function giving me a EventRef structure.. is there any way to use this to prevent a window to become active by certain circumstances?

thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in cocoa you can override NSWindow method `- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow`

it is invoked every time the window should become key.

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Also, NSControl's `setRefusesFirstResponder` can have an effect on controls moving to the front when clicked.